# vim missing bottom toolbar on Linux Mint

Tags: windows-7, vim, gvim, linux-mint

I've been trying Vim/Gvim, in both Windows and Linux (Mint), but something seems to be missing.

I'm missing the bottom "status" bar on the Linux version, the one that indicates the key pressed. Here's some screenshots:

Windows version with bottom toolbar: Notice the `q`, what I assume to be the line number, etc.

[image]

Linux version with no bottom toolbar:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set ruler showcmd
```

Comment: Thanks. It solved it, I also needed set showcmd wich was commented by default.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect that.